# React native animation crashes with Android

Tags: react-native

Very frustrated with this issue.

I am designing a game which requires animation. All works fine with Web part in Expo. The component as below:

```
return (  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={selectTarget}>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          width: 50,
          height: 50,
          backgroundColor: 'yellow',
          zIndex: 2,
          position: 'absolute',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          **transform: [
            { translateX: moveAnimation.x },
            { translateY: moveAnimation.y },
          ],**
          elevation: 2,
          left: 0, 
          top: 0,
        }}>
        <Image style={[imageStyle]} source={imagesAssets[color]} />
      </Animated.View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback> );
```

However it crashed on Android(fine with iOS), error as below: 
Error while updating 'transform' of a view managed by: RCTView

If I comment out the transform bit, it runs fine.

Due to performance issue, I add useDeviceDriver:true in the animation config, so I have to use transform.

Can anyone help me out the problem?

Comment: Is this similar? hope this could help you a little..
[link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9841#issuecomment-304657124)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the cause of the issue:

something wrong during moveAnimation calculation, undefined value will crash the app rather treat it as 0.